# Use of "this" in template classes cause error on parameter initialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have two template classes, CardTemplate and Handtemplate, designed to work with each other to do the grunt work common to both. Each is then subclassed to MyCard and MyHand, classes which would then contain code specific to those subclasses. The idea behind template classes was so that getting a card's hand would return (in this case) MyHand, which it does. The problem occurs in line 36, with errors noted following that line. At the point the code is instantiated, 'this' is a pointer to CardTemplate, while the instantiation of MyHand expects the argument to be MyCard. Here's the code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication> // Only way I can get access to std::vector in Qt

template <typename> class Tile;

template <typename handType>
class CardTemplate
{
public:
    CardTemplate() {}

    handType* GetHand() { return ourHand; }
    void SetHand(handType* hand) { ourHand = hand; }
    int  GetOurIndex();

    handType* ourHand;
};


template <typename cardType>
class HandTemplate
{
public:
    HandTemplate(){}

    void AddCard(cardType* card) { ourCards.push_back(card); }
    int  GetCardIndex(cardType* card) { return 0; /* do something like ourCards.indexOf(card); (Qt QVector)*/ }
    cardType* GetCardAt(int index) { ourCards.at(index); }

//    QVector<cardType*> ourCards;
    std::vector<cardType*> ourCards;
};

template <typename handType>
int CardTemplate<handType>::GetOurIndex()
{
    return ourHand->GetCardIndex(this);
    // Creator says: error: invalid conversion from ‘CardTemplate<MyHand>*’ to ‘MyCard*’ [-fpermissive]
    // Clang says:   error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'MyCard*' with an rvalue of type 'CardTemplate<MyHand>*'
    //               note: in instantiation of member function 'CardTemplate<MyHand>::GetOurIndex' requested here
    //               note: passing argument to parameter card here
}

class MyHand;
class MyCard : public CardTemplate<MyHand>
{
public:
    MyCard() {}
};

class MyHand : public HandTemplate<MyCard>
{
public:
    MyHand() {}
};

int main(void)
{
    MyHand aHand;
    MyCard aCard;

    aHand.AddCard(&aCard);
    aCard.SetHand(&aHand);
    aCard.GetHand();
    int index = aCard.GetOurIndex();

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Break the cycle... is it really necessary to have `MyCard` depend on `MyHand` and to have `MyHand` depend on `MyCard`?

Comment: I agree, there's no need for mutual dependency here. A hand is just a collection of cards and there's no need for a card to know what hand it belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing `int GetCardIndex(cardType* card) { return 0;` an instance of `CardTemplate<MyHand>`, by you must pass a `MyCart` instance. One way to fix this is to change the method signature to get a `CardTemplate<MyHand>` instance.

1. Add `using T = handType` in CardTemplate class, as follows:

   ```
   template <typename handType>
   class CardTemplate
   {
     public:
       using T = handType;

       CardTemplate() {}

       handType* GetHand() { return ourHand; }
       void SetHand(handType* hand) { ourHand = hand; }
       int  GetOurIndex();

       handType* ourHand;
   };
   ```
2. Change the `GetCardIndex()` method signature to get and instance of `CardTemplate<MyHand>` as follows:

   ```
   template <typename cardType>
   class HandTemplate
   {
      public:
        HandTemplate(){}

        void AddCard(cardType* card) { ourCards.push_back(card); }
        int  GetCardIndex(CardTemplate<typename cardType::T>& card){ (void)card; return 0; }
        cardType* GetCardAt(int index) { ourCards.at(index); }

       std::vector<cardType*> ourCards;
   };
   ```